# how to deploy a war File on Respberry Pie(Rip)?

Tags: java, linux, war

I am trying to deploy a war file on RPI which is an Linux device in webapps folder of tomcat 7 director.

When I am running this application I am getting

> requested resources not not available

If I am running same war file on my windows tomcat 7 server then it is working fine.

Can you please help me how to deploy war file on Rpi device

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information from the tomcat logs. The message is telling you that the web application is trying to use a resource that is not available on your Rpi. Look at the tomcat log, it should provide more details.

You need to know what resources your web app requires, database, thread pools, etc. When you deploy the war, do probably see error logs in the tomcat logs, that should help you figure out what the missing resource is.